# How to prevent unnecessary renders in a Component using useContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know how can I avoid unnecessary updates on a child `component` that does not receive `props`, but uses `useContext`.

I've added `React.memo` to the Child2 `component` for me to make some demo tests.

As you can see, when I change the `input` value which uses `context` to pass the data to `child1`, `Child2` does not re-render, as `React.memo` prevents this behavior.

How can I prevent unnecessary renders in Child1 as well? I know that React.memo won't work as it needs `props`, and with `context` this will not happen, as no `props` are being passed down to this `component`

`App.js`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child1 from "./Child1";
import Child2 from "./Child2";
import SillyContext from './context'

function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('Radha');
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const increaseCount = () => {
        setCount(prevState => prevState + 1)
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Child2 count={count}/>
            <button onClick={increaseCount}>Increase</button>
            <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(event => setName(event.target.value))}/>
            <SillyContext.Provider value={{name}}>
                <Child1/>
            </SillyContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`Child1`

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import SillyContext from './context'

export default function Child1() {
    const sillyContext = useContext(SillyContext)
    console.log('[Child 1 ran]')
    return (
        <div>
            <div>[Child 1]: {sillyContext.name}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`Child2`

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.memo(function Child2(props) {
    console.log('[Child2 Ran!]')
    return <div>[Child2] - Count: {props.count}</div>
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem due to which Child1 re-renders when count is updated is because you are passing a new object reference to Context Provider everytime.

Also If the App component re-renders, all element rendered within it re-render, unless they implement memoization or are PureComponent or use shouldComponentUpdate

You can make 2 changes to fix your re-rendering

- wrap Child1 with React.memo
- Use `useMemo` to memoize the object passed as value to provider

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Radha");
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount(prevState => prevState + 1);
  };

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ name }), [name]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child2 count={count} />
      <button onClick={increaseCount}>Increase</button>

      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)}
      />
      <SillyContext.Provider value={value}>
        <Child1 />
      </SillyContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Child2

```
const Child2 = React.memo(function(props) {
  console.log("[Child2 Ran!]");
  return <div>[Child2] - Count: {props.count}</div>;
});
```

---

Child 1

```
const Child1 = React.memo(function() {
  const sillyContext = useContext(SillyContext);
  console.log("[Child 1 ran]");
  return (
    <div>
      <div>[Child 1]: {sillyContext.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-monad-oil6i?file=/src/App.js:108-316)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I Thought that ```React.memo``` would not trigger inside ```Child1``` as it is a component which does not receive ```props```. I had figured regarding the need of isolating the ```object``` given by the ```provider```, but I could not understand how ```React.memo``` understands that in this specific case what the ```Provider``` is passing can be treated as ```props```, by wrapping the ```Child1 + Provier's obj```. Could you please explain why is that?

Comment: a component which doesn't receive props will also re-render if the parent re-renders which is why memo comes in handy. As far as using Context is concerned, its values are  not provided by props

Answer (score 0):

You can use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) inside `Child1` component. It doesn't solve rerendering problem, but it is some kind of improvement.

[Following snippet is third variant proposed by React core dev](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156)

> we could make our code a bit more verbose but keep it in a
>   single component by wrapping return value in useMemo and specifying
>   its dependencies. Our component would still re-execute, but React
>   wouldn't re-render the child tree if all useMemo inputs are the same.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, createContext, useContext, useMemo } = React;

const SillyContext = createContext();

const Child2 = React.memo(({count}) => {
    return <div>Count: {count}</div>
})         

const Child1 = () => {
    const {name} = useContext(SillyContext);
    
    return useMemo(() => {
    console.log('Child1');
      return <div>
        <div>Child 1: {name}</div>
      </div>}, [name])
}

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increaseCount = () => {
        setCount(prevState => prevState + 1)
  }

return <div>
  <Child2 count={count}/>
   <button onClick={increaseCount}>Increase</button>
  <Child1/>
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SillyContext.Provider value={{name: 'test'}}>
      <App />
    </SillyContext.Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This does not help.
- The `Child2` still re-render, it just not re-run the `useMemo` and have the same returned jsx code.
- You could say it helps because jsx code did not change. not really if you do not have another child component inside of it and do not use useMemo, React re-run that piece of jsx code but it won't re-pain the real DOM.
==> This does not really help

Comment: Updated answer. Thank you!